# TRUSTY: ssh connexion [root@127.0.0.1 Permission denied]

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ssh, password

I have this [script](https://github.com/ARCCN/ctltest/blob/master/benchmark_throughput.sh) that I am trying to execute on my machine Ubuntu 14.04, which indicates that I should **Manage the ssh keys on servers to avoid entering password each time**, which I didn't know how to, and the execution keeps asking me for a password (then I type the computer password) but it gives that the permission was denied,

As mentionned in the script, my machine will be both the server and client

Would you please help me about what to do, how should I configure the ssh connexion?

THANKS

Comment: I dont have a server, my question is based on using a script that calls a tools and tell him that the server and client are both this machine..

Comment: You have a server. Your target server is localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes, I meant it is not in another machine, so that solution didn't work for me

Comment: @Oxygenex: The solutions are actually the same, even if the server and client machine are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case "Server" and "Client" are that same computer.

### **Client side settings**

Generate SSH keys pair.

```
mkdir ~/.ssh

cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -C "My Comment for key" -t "access_key"
```

Detailed information about ssh-keygen options you can read in man page:

```
man ssh-keygen
```

After that you can find two files access_key and access_key.pub in ~/.ssh/

Create file with name "config" in your ~/.ssh directory.
This file allow you to set up different settings for each host you need to connect.

Here is simple content of this file

```
Host my.remote-host.com
   User remoteusername
   Identityfile ~/.ssh/access_key
```

**my.remote-host.com** - target host to connect to (localhost)

**remoteusername** - login name of user on remote machine

**Identityfile** - path to you **private** key

### **Server side settings**

How to enable "PublickKey" authentication:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Uncomment next lines:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**RSAAuthentication** - enable RSA keys support

**PubkeyAuthentication** - enable authentication by public keys

**AuthorizedKeysFile** - path to file that contain public keys

Restart your ssh server

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Create directory and set correct permissions

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Create file for public keys and set correct permissions

```
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Put your public key (access_key.pub) into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

You should use only one line per each key. Example:

```
ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAbC2kVOJpcnfu7UqKV44uZ/khiP9K7F...aoSe MyComment
```

### **How to completely disable password authentication**

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Change **PasswordAuthentication** from "yes" to "no"
Restart sshd server

```
sudo service sshd restart
```